# Installed Debian successfully in partition, I can only boot to Windows

Tags: debian, boot, partition

After finish installetion it searched for other operating systems and found freedos which I dont use. It didn't find windows

It told me that if I see my other operating system on the list it is safe to instal some linux boot manager

I didn't see my other operating system on the lists so I said no

Then an other screen told me that I have to make the partition bootable and instal the linux boot manager

I said yes

It told me to remove the usb before restart for not enter installation environment again.
It loaded something and then it only boots to windows

What I have to do?

Thanks

Comment: Are all systems installed in UEFI boot mode? Have you updated UEFI firmware? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair While more Ubuntu similar for Debian:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Comment: I don't know if all systems are installed in UEFI boot mode, because I dont know how to check it. I have not updated UEFI firmware as I don't know how. Sould I suppose that I have to make a live debian usb? This is what you mean by live installer? first time installing linux, I have a working tails usb tho

Comment: LIve installer is an install USB flash drive that can be booted in either in install mode or live mode where you can run/test system. You have to look to your vendor's support site for info on UEFI update. What brand/model system? Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I'm going to trust you, I will make media with that shady boot repair and I will return, hopefully casting pirate signals through Debian

Comment: You do not necessarily need Boot-Repair ISO, but can add it to any working live installer.

Comment: I boot with the boot repair usb, it was a menu from f2 to f6 with ''NO TEXTS!'' on the titles, in all of them... that's weird, I didn't do anything just left. I dont want easy fix software what is the manual way to put those 2 opereting systems on a boot manager? can be fixed from windows? windows are working on my system, debian doesn't work yet

Comment: Use your Ubuntu live installer in UEFI mode & add Boot-Repair ppa per directions in link. Manual way with chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088
UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380
To chroot, you need the same 32bit or 64 bit kernel. Best to use same version.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot